# Save and Load Model as .pb Using TFLearn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tflearn

I've trained DNN model using tflearn and saved it as checkpoint file, and the model performed well. I need to freeze the model so I can use it on android device later.

I've been searching a way to freeze my model directly from TFLearn but apparently tflearn hasn't provided such function as of now so I have to do it with tensorflow using [this code](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/964#issuecomment-350717215) to freeze my model into protobuf file. And I also got my output node name from tensorboard by using [this](https://gist.github.com/morgangiraud/249505f540a5e53a48b0c1a869d370bf#gistcomment-1934143) (same user) because using the name of output node I've explicitly given in my model apparently doesn't work in TFLearn and it just froze 0 variables from it.

It seemed to work fine as I successfully froze it into .pb file, but when I load that frozen graph in different runtime and make a prediction from it using `model.predict()`, it gave me a very wrong prediction as if my model hasn't even been trained yet.

This is my NN architecture.

```
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3], name='masuk')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 40, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 4)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 40, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 4)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 80, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 4)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 160, 2, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 4)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 500, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.75)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 32, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='keluar')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')
```

This is the code I used to try loading my .pb file.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with gfile.FastGFile(MODEL_NAME + '.frozen_graph.pb','rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        sess.graph.as_default()
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

This is for my assignment and I'm kinda new to tensorflow (and machine learning in general) so is there something I miss here to make it work?